# All possible combination of 3 numbers in a set in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, combinatorics

I want to print all possible combination of 3 numbers from the set (**0 ... n-1**), while each one of those combinations is unique. I get the variable **n** via this code:

```
n = raw_input("Please enter n: ")
```

But I'm stuck at coming up with the algorithm. Any help please?

Comment: did you try anything?? it would be nice to add your code in your question.

Answer (score 10):

```
from itertools import combinations
list(combinations(range(n),3))
```

This would work as long as you are using later than Python 2.6

Answer (score 3):

If you want all the possible combinations with repetition in values and differ in position you need to use product like this:

```
from itertools import product
t = range(n)
print set(product(set(t),repeat = 3))
```

for example, if n = 3, the output will be:

```
set([(0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)])
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

`itertools` is your friend here, specifically `permutations`.

Demo:

```
from itertools import permutations 

for item in permutations(range(n), 3): 
    print item
```

This is assuming you have Python 2.6 or newer.

Comment: I think you meant `itertools.combinations`

Comment: @Duncan I think the OP's definition of combinations might be more general than that of programming, so I decided to include it.

Answer (score 1):

```
combos = []
for x in xrange(n):
    for y in xrange(n):
        for z in xrange(n):
             combos.append([x,y,z])
```